# How to iframe a page from same domain with X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We have this page, www.ourdomain.com/home.html

Inside home.html, there is an iframe with src set to yyy.ourdomain.com/index.html. All pages on yyy.ourdomain.com have X-Frame-Options set to SAMEORIGIN. And because of this header, the iframe content doesn't load. I get this error.

*Firefox - Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://yyy.ourdomain.com/index.html does not permit cross-origin framing.*

*Chrome - Refused to display 'http://yyy.ourdomain.com/index.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.*

Both home.html and index.html have this line of javascript code -

`document.domain = 'ourdomain.com';`

How can I make this work?

PS - I don't have the option of removing the X-Frame-Options header.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably can't use frames then. Perhaps ajax will do what you need.

Comment: For example, pull the entire page in via ajax, and load the content into a modal or something with javascript.

Comment: If you're developing something for your own use, and are willing to use a browser plugin, you can use something like Ignore X-Frame headers plugin for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe?hl=en-US). That obviously doesn't help if you're trying to solve a problem for general-use or production code.

Comment: It is fir general public. Is there no other way to make it work, other than remove the header from the response?

Answer (score 2):

The headers `X-Frame-Options: DENY` or `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` won't allow you in any way to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`.

The only working way I found, is to create a proxy page in the main domain that load the html content of the requested subdomain page.

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

for more information